# Java: Group By then Map

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have a stream of `Event`s

```
public class Event {
    Location location;
    double turnout;
    //... other fields & getters
}
```

And a statistics class `EventStatistics`

```
public class EventStatistics {
    // Stats properties e.g. turnout standard deviation/median

    public EventStatistics(List<Event> events) {
        // Generate stats
    }
}
```

I need to group all the events by location & create a map of location and event statistics `Map<Location, EventStatistics>`

The group by is just:

```
Map<Location, List<Event>> byLocation = events.stream().collect(groupingBy(Event::getLocation));
```

I know there is an overloaded `groupingBy(function, collector)` collector. Can I use somehow this to generate my `Map<Location, EventStatistics>` in a single stream?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All you need is [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<Location, EventStatistics> result = 
    events.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getLocation,
                                         Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                             Collectors.toList(), 
                                             EventStatistics::new)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct your own [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) using [`Collector.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-), like this:

```
Map<Location, EventStatistics> collect = events.stream().collect(groupingBy(Event::getLocation,
        Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
                     List::add,
                     (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                     EventStatistics::new)
));
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me.  `ArrayList::new` doesn't infer the Event type. I need to specify `ArrayList<Event>::new`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `EventStatistics` were to be able to accept single `Events` instead of a full list, and a method to merge two statistics, as in

```
EventStatistics {
    public EventStatistics() {}
    public void addEvent(Event e);
    public EventStatistics merge(EventStatistics toMerge);
}
```

then [you can do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-)

```
groupingBy(Event::getLocation, Collector.of(EventStatistics::new, EventStatistics::accept, EventStatistics::merge));
```

Here, the argument-less constructor is the `Supplier`, the `accept` is the `accumulator`, and the `merge` is the `combiner`.